# Disable cart sharing between different Stores of website in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2.2.2, session, quote, shopping-cart

My website is with Three different `Stores` and I'd like to disable the `cart sharing` feature between stores. So when I switch from one store to the other store, the product in my cart shouldn't be valid or not display to another store.

```
Product added to the specific store should be displayed on the specific store only.
```

Comment: I think you have one web -> one store -> multiple views    ?

Comment: I have 1 website, 2 stores and 2 store views (one for each store).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this works, it's just an idea: The quote has the functionality to specify the stores which are sharing the quote. By default this are all stores of a website. Anyway if it is possible to set a list of spefic stores before loading the quote, I think it is possible to restrict the quote to a subset of all stores of a website, in your case just to the actual store.

One idea could be to set the store restriction in a plugin before the `get` method in `Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository`, which should always be called when a quote is loaded.

Again, it's just an idea which might not work and the code is not tested and just to demonstrate my thoughts.

```
class MyPlugin{

    protected $storeManager;

    public function __construct( 
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    ){
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    public function beforeGet(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository $quoteRepository, 
         $cartId, 
         array $sharedStoreIds
    ){
        return [$cartId, [$this->storeManager->getStore()->getId()]];
    }
}
```

Looking forward to hearing what you think about this approach.

Comment: I will try and update if it works.

Comment: Great Man !!! :) +1

Comment: Tried it. Only items are hidden from minicart section but they are visible is other sections like cart, checkout.

Comment: I tried the above solution. Working fine but not after login. Any guide?

Answer (score 1):

Go to folder location vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/ open file Session.php. Now search _getQuoteIdKey function in this file and replace website id with store id.

Replace this line

> return 'quote_id_' . $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId() 
>   with this line
>   return 'quote_id_' . $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getStoreId();

now your all stores carts who belongs to same website works independently.

Comment: But this is not working for API calls. /V1/carts/mine returns the existing quote id

Answer (score 0):

By default, Magento support to share cart between websites and to do so you need to ensure the following settings:

1. Cookie Path & Cookie Domain

[image: cookie setting]

2. Share Customer Account -> Global

[image: share customer account]

To disable cart sharing functionality, I suggest to change your cookie domain. E.g

store 1: `https://mystore.com` => cookie domain: `.mystore.com`

store 2: `https://mystore2.com` => cookie domain: `.mystore2.com`

And disable the share customer account functionality, otherwise you may need to find a way to regenerate the session ID between stores (SID), Magento store switcher automatically added SID for store, I recommend not use their store switcher but develop your owned store switcher to avoid SID appended.

Hope this help.

Comment: I have only one website and loading second store using website.com/store2 . Is is compulsory to create 2 websites?

Comment: @amitshree If your store using domain such as `website.com/store2`, you should look into the cookie path instead of the cookie domain.

Comment: I have changed cookie path as /default and /retail for both stores view. Still I see cart is shared.